# Ignoring null values when using Regex Validator in Data Annotation

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations

I'm having an issue with a nullable field with a Regex Format for a Phone Field

Im using ASP.net MVC 3

Here is my Regex Format Validator in my Data Annotation

```
[Display(Name = "Phone")]
[RegularExpression(@"^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Phone Number")]
public string Phone { get; set; }
```

My question is, is there a workaround to ignore the field when the value is null and hide the Error Message to it? Thanks

Comment: You should not be getting any error message if the value is `null`

Comment: @StephenMuecke i forgot to mention that i used masking using jquery `$('#Phone').mask("?(999)999-9999");` do you think it can affect the validation?

Comment: Must be, because a validation check will not be fired if the value is `null` (unless you have a `[Required]` attribute as well)